# MongoDB merge default values to each documents if not exists

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I have two collection students and countries, countries collection has some default values, I want to merge countries default values to students collection by MongoDB query

students collection some documents

```
[
 {
  "name": "John"
 },
 {
  "name": "Tom"
 },
 {
  "name": "Harry",
  "country": {
     "AUS": 150
  }
 }
]
```

countries collection some documents

```
[{
 "name": "AUS",
 "value": 100
},
{
 "name": "CAN",
 "value": 200
 }]
```

For students collection country may or may not present

Now I want to write a query in MongoDB which will return below documents by using students and countries collection

```
[
 {
  "name": "John",
  "country": {
     "AUS": 100,
     "CAN": 200
  }
 },
 {
  "name": "Tom",
  "country": {
     "AUS": 100,
     "CAN": 200
  }
 },
 {
  "name": "Harry",
  "country": {
     "AUS": 150,
     "CAN": 200
  }
 }
]
```

If country value present in students collection then it will take that country value from there and rest of the values from countries collection, example given in student "Harry"
If no country value present in student then we will take all default values from countries collection.

Any help appreciated, if required we can redesign students and countries collection.
Is it not possible in MongoDB single query, do we need to write some custom code in NodeJS application

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [$lookup with custom pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/index.html#uncorrelated-subquery) to get all the countries data into documents from `students` collection and then you need to use [$objectToArray](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/objectToArray/index.html) and [$arrayToObject](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayToObject/index.html) to dynamically generate keys and values of `contry` object. Since the data from `country` is a first argument of [$concatArrays](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/concatArrays/index.html) it will overwrite default values

```
db.students.aggregate([
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "countries",
            pipeline: [ { $project: { _id: 0, k: "$name", v: "$value" } } ],
            as: "countries"
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            name: 1,
            country: {
                $arrayToObject: {
                    $concatArrays: [ { $ifNull: [ { $objectToArray: "$country" }, [] ] }, "$countries" ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
])
```

Comment: in project statement will be {
        $project: {
            name: 1,
            country: {
                $arrayToObject: {
                    $concatArrays: [ "$countries" ,{ $ifNull: [ { $objectToArray: "$country" }, [] ] }]
                }
            }
        }
    }

Comment: @JohneDoe I think the order determines if the default value or the existing one will be taken. You can check both ways and see which one works for you